# Parsing data to make new data appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am creating a commenting system. As of now, I am trying to return a comment posted, but only the new posted comment, using AJAX, with `setInterval` and parsing JSON data. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am getting a synatax error: unexpected end of JSON input.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong or if there is a better way of doing this?

HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="comment-form">
            <textarea id="home_comment" name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment..." maxlength="1000" required></textarea><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
            <input id="comment-button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Post">
        </form>
        <div id="comment-container">
```

AJAX

```
function commentRetrieve(){

        $.ajax({ 
                url: "ajax-php/comment-retrieve.php",
                type: "get",
                success: function (data) {
                //  console.log(data);
                    if (data == "Error!") {
                        alert("Unable to retrieve comment!");
                        alert(data);
                    } else {
                        var array = JSON.parse(data);
                        $(array).each(function($value) {
                            if($('#comment-container').find('#comment-' + $value.id).length == 0) {
                                $('#comment-container').prepend($value.html);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
                    console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
                }
            });


    }
    setInterval(commentRetrieve, 3000);
```

PHP

```
$user = new User();

        //Get the last insert id
            $select_comments_sql = "
            SELECT c. *, p.user_id, p.img
            FROM home_comments AS c
            INNER JOIN (SELECT max(id) as id, user_id 
                        FROM profile_img 
                        GROUP BY user_id) PI
              on PI.user_id = c.user_id
            INNER JOIN profile_img p
              on PI.user_id = p.user_id
             and PI.id = p.id
            ORDER BY c.id DESC
        ";

        if ($select_comments_stmt = $con->prepare($select_comments_sql)) {
            //$select_comments_stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $select_comments_stmt->execute();
            $rows = $select_comments_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $comment_id = $row['id'];
                $comment_user_id = $row['user_id'];
                $comment_username = $row['username'];
                $home_comments = $row['comment'];
                $comment_date = $row['date'];
                $commenter_user_id = $row['user_id'];
                $commenter_img = $row['img'];
                $commenter_img = '<img class="home-comment-profile-pic" src=" '.$commenter_img.'">';
                if ($home_comments === NULL) {
                    echo 'No comments found.';
                } else {
                    $html = "";
                    $html .= '<div class="comment-post-box">';
                    $html .= $commenter_img;
                    $html .= '<div class="comment-post-username">'.$comment_username. '</div>';
                    $html .= '<div>'.$comment_date. '</div>';
                    $html .= '<div class="comment-post-text">'.$home_comments. '</div>';
                    $html .= '</div>';
                    array('id' => $comment_id, 'html' => $html);
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit: image

[image]

Comment: Do you get the error while posting a new comment or is it while fetching the data?

Comment: Neither. It only posts the error when trying to do this with JSON. Before I was just echoing all the info, but it was causing all of my comments to post over and over. In short my SELECT query works, if that is what you were getting at.